# Confusion with subclassing a threading class, and inheritance

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, inheritance, subclassing

I am trying to understand how to subclass a Thread, 
and I am confused with some details of inheritance.
It seems if I want to modify 
the `__init__` I need to call super as follows:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, url, browser, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.url = url
        self.browser = browser
```

This allows me to inherit all of the parents init 
attributes as I am using `*args, **kwargs` and I can call `MyThread._target` within the initializer and it works.

However it seems I don't need to call super to 
modify the run method. I have seen this example online:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, number, logger):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.number = number
        self.logger = logger

    def run(self):
        """
        Run the thread
        """
        #modification to run method but no call to it
        logger.debug('Calling doubler')
        doubler(self.number, self.logger)
```

Here it seems they are overwriting the parent init with The `threading.Thread.__init__(self`) ? 
However, the `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` is not 
calling any parameters, so it's essentially an empty `__init__` and doesn't acquire any of the parents attributes such as target, args, group. If I try to call `MyThread._target` I get an error.
So it seems as if they are creating a completely new `init`. So why even call `threading.Thread.__init__` if you are not going to inherit any
attributes?

And why doesn't run method require the call to the original  `threading.Thread.run()` if they are modifying the run method?
It seems only init is requiring the call to the original init for modification, but run doesn't require so.

Now another aspect I was confused about was, when I attempted to access the `._target` after super inheritance; the attribute wasn't found in the run method:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, number, style, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.number = number
        self.style = style
        print(self._target) # works here

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().run(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self._target) # leads to error
        print('thread has ended')




custom = MyThread(target = print, number = 3, style ="red", args = ("test",))
custom.run()
```

OUTPUT:

```
<built-in function print>
test

Traceback:
custom.run()...........
print(self._target)
AttributeError: 'MyThread' object has no attribute '_target'[/python]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example which calls `Thread.__init__` is less general than it could be. `Thread.__init__` does, in fact, take some parameters, but they all have default values, so strictly speaking, you don't *have* to call it with any arguments.

`Thread.run` essential does nothing except run the callable passed as the `target` option to `Thread.__init__`. If you don't pass any such argument, there's no real need to call `Thread.run`; the overridden method does all the actual work.

Note that when using `super`, it's important to accept and pass on unknown arguments, not so much because you want the `Thread` methods to get any required arguments, but because your class doesn't *know* what class's method might be called next. That is determined by the runtime time of `self`, not the subclass of `Thread`.

Comment: Also, if you use `target=`, then the default `run()` method just runs the `target`, and after it is run, it deletes `self._target` to eliminate the possibility of re-running the same `Thread`. That is why you get the `AttributeError`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much to both of you. That clears up a lot.